# Collecting data with RSelenium- looping dropdown menus with buttons

Tags: javascript, r, button, dropdown, rselenium

I am having difficulties with collecting data on changes in Spanish municipalities over time.  I have been trying to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314380/collecting-table-data-from-a-asp-webpage-over-with-a-for-loop-using-rselenium) as a guide, but I think I am running into problems because in order to move from one dropdown menu to another, a button needs to be clicked.  I can't figure out where to work the button into the code.

What I have so far:

```
#access web page
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName="firefox", port=4444)
remDr$open(silent=T)
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(3000)
remDr$navigate("http://www.ine.es/intercensal/")
```

I can access the tables I want individually by entering values into each of three elements (Autonomous community, Province, and Municipality) and clicking buttons, for example:

```
remDr$executeScript("document.getElementById('cmbCCAA').value = 1;")
ConsultProv <- remDr$findElement(using = 'name', value = 'btnBuscarProv')
ConsultProv$clickElement()

remDr$executeScript("document.getElementById('cmbProv').value = 4;")
ConsultMuni <- remDr$findElement(using = 'name', value = 'btnBuscarMuni')
ConsultMuni$clickElement()

remDr$executeScript("document.getElementById('cmbMuni').value = 5861;")
SubmitMuni <- remDr$findElement(using = 'name', value = 'btnBuscarGeo')
SubmitMuni$clickElement()
```

And while the code may be inelegant (apologies, but I just began learning R), I can pull individual table data with:

```
readname <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = '.TITULOH3')
namedata <- readname$getElementText()
cleanname1 <- gsub("Province: ", "", namedata)
separatename1 <- str_split(cleanname1, "Municipality: ")
separatename2 <- unlist(separatename1, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
trimmed <- trimws(separatename2)
names(trimmed) <- data.frame("Province", "Municipality", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
finalname <- t(trimmed)

table <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])

readdfdata <- readHTMLTable(table, skip.rows = c(1, 2, 4, 5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tabledfdata <- as.data.frame(readdfdata[2])
names(tabledfdata) <- c("skip", "dfpop1842", "dfpop1857", "dfpop1860", "dfpop1877", "dfpop1887", "dfpop1897", 
        "dfpop1900", "dfpop1910", "dfpop1920", "dfpop1930", "dfpop1940", "dfpop1950", "dfpop1960", 
        "dfpop1970", "dfpop1981", "dfpop1991", "dfpop2001", "dfpop2011")
cleandftable <- subset(tabledfdata, select = -c(skip))
finaldfpop <- cleandftable

readdjdata <- readHTMLTable(table, skip.rows = c(1, 2, 3, 5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tabledjdata <- as.data.frame(readdjdata[2])
names(tabledjdata) <- c("skip", "djpop1842", "djpop1857", "djpop1860", "djpop1877", "djpop1887", "djpop1897", 
        "djpop1900", "djpop1910", "djpop1920", "djpop1930", "djpop1940", "djpop1950", "djpop1960", 
        "djpop1970", "djpop1981", "djpop1991", "djpop2001", "djpop2011")
cleandjtable <- subset(tabledjdata, select = -c(skip))
finaldjpop <- cleandjtable

readhhdata <- readHTMLTable(table, skip.rows = c(1, 2, 3, 4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tablehhdata <- as.data.frame(readhhdata[2])
names(tablehhdata) <- c("skip", "hh1842", "hh1857", "hh1860", "hh1877", "hh1887", "hh1897", 
        "hh1900", "hh1910", "hh1920", "hh1930", "hh1940", "hh1950", "hh1960", 
        "hh1970", "hh1981", "hh1991", "hh2001", "hh2011")
cleanhhtable <- subset(tablehhdata, select = -c(skip))
finalhhpop <- cleanhhtable

readchange <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = '.alteraciones')
changedata <- readchange$getElementText()
separatechange1 <- str_split(changedata, "\\n ")
separatechange2 <- unlist(separatechange1, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
finalchange <- t(separatechange2)

complete <- data.frame(finalname, finaldfpop, finaldjpop, finalhhpop, finalchange, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

But how do I loop this process in order to collect data for all municipalities?  I tried using the changeFun from the previous answer while also incorporating the buttons, but the following code gets stuck:

```
#Pre-existing changeFun
changeFun <- function(value, elementName, targetName){
  changeElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", elementName)
  script <- paste0("arguments[0].value = '", value, "'; arguments[0].onchange();")
  remDr$executeScript(script, list(changeElem))
  targetCodes <- c()
  while(length(targetCodes) == 0){
    targetElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", targetName) 
    target <- xmlParse(targetElem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]])
    targetCodes <- sapply(querySelectorAll(target, "option"), xmlGetAttr, "value")[-1]
    target <- sapply(querySelectorAll(target, "option"), xmlValue)[-1]
    if(length(targetCodes) == 0){
      Sys.sleep(0.5)
    }else{
      out <- list(target, targetCodes)
    }
  }
  return(out)
}

#This part works fine in getting autonoma names and codes
autonomas <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", "cmbCCAA") 
autonomasdata <- autonomas$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
autocodes <- sapply(querySelectorAll(xmlParse(autonomasdata), "option"), xmlGetAttr, "value")[-1]
autos <- sapply(querySelectorAll(xmlParse(autonomasdata), "option"), xmlValue)[-1]

#But this part for getting Province and Municipality names and codes does not run
autonoma <- list()
for(x in seq_along(autocodes)){
  ConsultProv <- remDr$findElement(using = 'name', value = 'btnBuscarProv')
  ConsultProv$clickElement()
  province <- changeFun(autocodes[[x]], "cmbCCAA", "cmbProv")
  municipality <- lapply(province[[2]], function(y){
  ConsultMuni <- remDr$findElement(using = 'name', value = 'btnBuscarMuni')
  ConsultMuni$clickElement()
    municipality <- changeFun(y, "cmbProv", "cmbMuni")
    municipality}
    )
    list(municipality)}
  ) 
  autonoma[[x]] <- list(province, municipality)
}
```

Any advice on how to make the loop work would be greatly appreciated.  I think the problem I am having is in incorporating the button clicking, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  Thanks!

**Edits**
I have done some messing around with this, and I still think the issue is with incorporating the button clicking.  I have created a Frankenstein's-monster of code below that does... something.  Basically, I think I need to incorporate JavaScript in an executeScript command somewhere, either in the ChangeFun or in the larger code.  Not sure if me narrowing it down in this way helps at all, but I thought I would update everyone on my (lack of) progress.

```
 sel_auto <- remDr$findElement(using = 'name', value = 'cmbCCAA')
 raw_auto <- sel_auto$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
 num_auto <- sapply(querySelectorAll(xmlParse(raw_auto), "option"), xmlGetAttr, "value")[-1]
 nam_auto <- sapply(querySelectorAll(xmlParse(raw_auto), "option"), xmlValue)[-1]
 for (i in seq_along(num_auto)){
   remDr$executeScript("document.getElementById('cmbCCAA').value = 1;")
   clk_auto <- remDr$findElement(using = 'name', value = 'btnBuscarProv')
   clk_auto$clickElement()
   sel_prov <- remDr$findElement(using = 'name', value = 'cmbProv')
   raw_prov <- sel_prov$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
   num_prov <- sapply(querySelectorAll(xmlParse(raw_prov), "option"), xmlGetAttr, "value")[-1]
   nam_prov <- sapply(querySelectorAll(xmlParse(raw_prov), "option"), xmlValue)[-1]
   for (j in seq_along(num_prov)){
     sel_prov$clickElement()
     clk_prov <- remDr$findElement(using = 'name', value = 'btnBuscarMuni')
     clk_prov$clickElement()
     sel_muni <- remDr$findElement(using = 'name', value = 'cmbMuni')
     raw_muni <- sel_muni$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
     num_muni <- sapply(querySelectorAll(xmlParse(raw_muni), "option"), xmlGetAttr, "value")[-1]
     nam_muni <- sapply(querySelectorAll(xmlParse(raw_muni), "option"), xmlValue)[-1]
   }
 }
```